# Search for a specific value in an Associative array

Tags: php

I have an associative array that is created by a query using the following code:

```
$query = ("SELECT `time_stamp`, `EAE` FROM `table`");
$stmt = $con->query($query);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $rows;
```

To access each value I usually use a `for` loop such as:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($rows) ; $i++)
{
     echo $rows[$i]['time_stamp'].' '.$rows[$i]['EAE'].'<br>';
}
```

However, I want to access a value that is registered in a specific time_stamp. To do so I am having trouble using the function `array_search`. I've tried setting it up like this:

```
$sum_a = array_search(date('Y-m-d', $rows[$j]['time_stamp'])." 00:00:00", $rows);
```

But it doesn't find anything. I can't find a way to use this function with a double scope array. Do you guys know how I can use it? Or if there is another way that doesn't involve accessing the database again or running a loop on the whole array?

PS:I've also tried to detect a value using `in_array` but it didn't find anything.

Comment: why not add a where clause on the query instead

Comment: For my case that doesn't help, because I am doing a loop to cover all the values, and during this loop I need to access a specific previous value. It's quite confusing and the only answer I can think of is to reaccess the db.

Comment: then just do that checking while inside the loop instead. anyways, you cant use an array search on a multi dimensional, its suppose to work on a flat one.

Comment: If you can't get the value during the loop, then it's not bad design to have a separate function which queries the database for a specific value. No need to be confused :-)

Comment: Ok, you just gave me an idea to work on. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$rows` in your case will be multidimensional array. `array_search` loops only first dimension - thats why your code is not working.

You can get values of specified column using.

```
$column = array_map(function($element){return $element['time_stamp'];}, $rows);
```

For PHP 5.5+ you can use `array_column`.

And then you can use own code

```
$sum_a = array_search(date('Y-m-d', $rows[$j]['time_stamp'])." 00:00:00", $column);
```